# Idioms for enormous scale and great quality

Tags: idioms

How do you describe "legendary scale" events/entities?

One I know is *an X to end all Xes*

Some say X *of epic proportions*

What other idioms or hyperboles could one use for something "extremely noteworthy"?

Comment: This question is open ended. Avoid asking subjective questions where every answer is equally valid. (from the FAQ)

Answer (score 3):

"The mother of all X." = the greatest example of its kind

But it's casual.

Answer (score 1):

There's the King James idiom, which I think is borrowed from the Hebrew, "X of Xes", as in "Holy of Holies" and "King of Kings".

Of course there are all sorts of superlatives which can be exagerrated to hyperbole: "The greatest X in history", "the best X in the world", etc.